# change direction mtext x label

Tags: r, plot

I've found plenty of posts about changing the direction of x labels using `las()`, but I haven't found much about how to manipulate `mtext()`. I've used `mtext` to supplement a figure using the following code:

```
arrows(3.85, 0.5, 3.85, 0.05,lwd=3, length=.1, xpd = TRUE)
mtext(side=4, "Increasing precipitation", font=2,line=2)
```

I'm placing it on the y axis of right side of the figure but the text still reads from bottom to top and looks strange. Is there a way to flip this text so it reads top to bottom? Using `las()` and others only seems to allow me to change it from parallel to perpendicular. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `text` would be easier. If you use mtext, you'd have to use `side = 2` and mess with the `line` argument unless there is a way to rotate the `mtext` labels that I don't know of.

```
plot(0, bty = 'l')
p <- par('usr')
text(p[2], mean(p[3:4]), labels = 'Some text', xpd = NA, srt = -90)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this still reads bottom to top. I'm looking for a way to rotate that text 180 degrees so it reads top to bottom.